# using @JsonIdentityInfo or @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference causes my property in a class to be ignored when parsing into it

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jackson-databind

i have been having hibernate circular dependency issues this are the class below:

```
   @Entity
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="id")
    public class Task extends DefaultEntity{


        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "cloth_model_id")
        //@JsonIgnore
        private ClothModel clothModel;

        private String details;

        private boolean completed;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
        private Employee employee;
}




   @Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="id")
public class ClothModel extends DefaultEntity {

    private ClothingType clothingType;

    private int quantity;

    private double amount;

    @Transient
    private String modelStructure;

    private String savedUrl;


    @Transient
    //@JsonManagedReference
    private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
}



 @MappedSuperclass
public class DefaultEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "Time",columnDefinition= "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateCreated;
```

**i removed the getters and setters, so the code wouldn't be too much**

When i apply the @JsonIdentityInfo or @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference to both the ClothModel.class and Task.class, i notice that in the  clothModel property in the Task.class will be ignored when i try writing a JSON to it, it acts like i am using a @Jsonignore annotation. Why is this and why isn't there a proper 100% working fix for Hibernate circular recursion.

Comment: What do you want to achieve anyway? because the annotations you mentioned does exactly what you said. They are used to stop any field from serializing when parsed into json

Comment: This is a Jackson issue, unrelated to Hibernate, and no, there is no way to use circular references and have them print something.

Comment: @Anas i want to retrieve a ClothModel which has a list of tasks, but i cannot because it will cause a stackoverflow error

Comment: @coladict i just want to retrieve a clothModel which has a list of tasks so i can parse them to my view, but i cant cause of the circular reference which causes a stackoverflow error. any issue on how to solve this please

Comment: What you have done is called bi-directional mapping and unless you make it uni directional or use the annotations you mentioned you would get a stack overflow error

Comment: You can add the JsonIgnore/JsonBackReference in the child entity's field where it points to the parent entity. If you want it to also print something, then you're out of luck.

Comment: @Anas can i have a code demo on how to make it unidirectional ?

Comment: Its easy, decide which ever your parent class is. Have a list of child objects in that class. Goto child class and remove the reference of parent class(object of parent class)